# How to get selected item from Exontrol.WindowList in delphi?

Tags: windows, delphi

My program wants to read data from another program, test.exe.  Test.exe contains a listbox control, and when the list box's selected item is changed, my program wants to get the selected item content.

When I use `SendMessage(handle, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0)` to send a message to test.exe (which should return the index of the selected item in the list box), the program returns 0, but the list box's selected item index is not 0. What's wrong?

I used Spy++ to look at test.exe, and found that the list box's class name is `Exontrol.WindowList`. Is this control a list box or another control?  How can I get the list box's selected item?

By the way, my program is written in Delphi.

Comment: Did you contemplate using one of the automation APIs rather than window message hacking? And from a quick look at their site, it seems quite likely that this Exontrol control is not a list box.

Comment: Also if SendMessage(handle, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0) is your real code, you're probably sending a message to your own form. (Handle is a property of all VCL TWinControl-based classes, so if this code is in, say, a button event handler on the form, Handle probably refers to the form's handle unless you've overriden it with a local variable. Either way, it's bad variable naming.) Otherwise, are you sure you're sending a message to the right window handle? How do you get the handle?

Comment: @DavidM Unless `handle` is a local variable

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, I mentioned that :)  But it's still bad code style to introduce a variable with the same name as a variable in higher scope. We haven't seen the full code so don't know what the OP is doing, although I think your first comment is right and the message is unlikely to work at all.

Comment: Since you're using spy++, to determine if the control is really a listbox, you can look f.i. if the parent of the control is receiving any WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX.

Answer (score 0):

The Exontrol.WindowList is not a subclass/superclass of Windows's ListBox, ListView, or any other. In conclusion, you can not use standard API for other designed windows, to get the selection in the control. You need to get a reference to the object that created the Exontrol.WindowList and handles the selection using the Items collection.

Regards,
MF

Comment: "You need to get a reference to
the object that created the Exontrol.WindowList and handles
the selection using the Items collection." How is that viable when the control is in another process?

Comment: How are you going to do that? Do you know many apps that expose their GUIs through out-of-proc COM? Is that even possible? What makes you think that this app does?